# Oracle Invoker Rights Documentation Error?

Tags: oracle, security, plsql, authid

[Oracle 19c Security Guide 8.2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/managing-security-for-definers-rights-and-invokers-rights.html#GUID-5ECAD7B4-BF99-4A36-B770-2132A43ED5A5)

> "The user of a procedure who is not its owner is called the *invoker*."

[Oracle 19c Security Guide 8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/managing-security-for-definers-rights-and-invokers-rights.html#GUID-74D3BC6B-1371-4AA8-B7E7-ECB84394B9D4)

> "When the invoker runs an invoker's rights procedure, this user temporarily has *all* of the privileges of the invoker."

Isn't this last statement 8.3 trivially true (like a tautology) when applying the definition of *invoker* from 8.2?  The invoker is "this user", so of course "this user" has the privileges of the invoker because they are one and the same.  Furthermore, I do not understand what is temporary about it.  The fact that this sentence is in the documentation, has an emphasis on the word "all", and specifically mentions temporary behaviour makes me think I'm totally missing the point of what the docs are trying to tell me.

Or, is this a documentation error and it meant to say,

> "When the invoker runs an invoker's rights procedure, this **procedure** temporarily has *all* of the privileges of the invoker."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probable explanation *contrasting* the *all invoker privileges* (from 8.2) `The privileges of the procedure's definer must be granted directly to the procedure owner, not granted through roles`

Comment: As MB said - this has to do with which user privileges are honored during the execution of a procedure (or function or package etc.) While executing a procedure with definer's rights, only the directly granted privileges (not those acquired via roles) are considered. While executing a procedure with invoker's rights, ALL of the invoker's rights (regardless of how they were granted) are considered. It's temporary - only for the duration of that program unit (function, procedure, etc.) - although it's not clear why this clarification is necessary in the documentation.